# Where does AWS Amplify DataStore store its data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have been looking for a Firebase Firestore equivalence to AWS World, I came across AWS Amplify and saw the DataStore module. From watching this video I see it does pretty much exactly what I expected, that is being about to have a real-time data mechanism, I watched this [video from the official Amplify website](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/js/) but I haven't really seen where the data get a store or is this just a pub-sub kind of mechanism where I need to additionally write code which writes data to where I want it to be store e.g to DynamoDb or any other destination on Cloud?

Comment: Datastore stores your data inside an DynamoDB table you defined and also inside indexdb inside your browser

Comment: Thanks, I now understand. I will check a video that shows that the one I watched doesn't demonstrate the DynamoDB part. Thanks, if you have any recommended Youtube video please share the link. Thanks